# NativeBase error while running jest: `useTheme` must be used within `NativeBaseConfigProvider`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, native-base

I'm having this error when trying to run the Jests in my project:

```
NativeBase error while running jest: `useTheme` must be used within `NativeBaseConfigProvider`
```

I'm using Expo, React Native and NativeBase. Everything is working fine, just the tests that are not running.

What I've tried so far:

- Wrap all app elements in `NativeBaseProvider` (meaning that I'm calling it in App.js);
- Wrapping the component being tested in `NativeBaseProvider`;
- Wrapping the component being rendered in the test in `NativeBaseProvider`.

I don't know what do to anymore.

Help?!

Comment: Can you paste your test code? It seems that you are not wrapping the tests in the NativeBaseProvider. This is needed in the tests, not just your app. https://docs.nativebase.io/testing